# How to auto fill datagridview fields on textbox leav event of the same datagridview

Tags: c#, .net

I am doing a windows application sales module where i am adding multiple items into a datagridview, In my datagridview i have itemcode, barcode, itemname(combobox), quantity, rate ect.
When i enter the item code i need to auto fill the rest of my coloums with the values according to the itemcode saved in database
[mydatagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmb4q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CellValueChanged event of the data grid view control.
Below is a simple example demonstrating the capture of the item code entered, passing this to a business layer which in turn calls a database layer and returns you a populated item for use on the grid.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       //Bind cell value changed event or set in designer.
       dgGridView.CellValueChanged += dgGridView_CellValueChanged;
 }

    private void dgGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == -1)
            return;

        if (e.ColumnIndex > 0)
            return;

        var myBL = new MyBL();

        switch (e.ColumnIndex)
        {
            case 0: //Item Code Column
                var itemCodeEntered = dgGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
                var itemData = myBL.GetItemData(itemCodeEntered);
                dgGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = itemData.ItemCode;
                dgGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = itemData.BarCode;
                break;

            case 1: //Bar code column
                // Do other stuff here.
                break;

            //etc...
        }

    }
```

Ensure you encapsulate you business and data layer actions in a separate class. I return a class called "MyItemData"

```
    public class MyItemData
    {
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string BarCode { get; set; }
        //etc...
    }

public class MyBL
{
    public MyItemData GetItemData(string itemCode)
    {
        var myDL = new MyDBLayer();
        var itemDataSet = myDL.ReturnItemData(itemCode);

        var newItem = new MyItemData();
        newItem.ItemCode = itemCode;
        newItem.BarCode = itemDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["BarCode"].ToString();

        //etc...

        return newItem;
    }
}


public class MyDBLayer
{
    public DataSet ReturnItemData(string itemCode)
    {
        DataSet myDataSet;
        //Query database and set dataSet
        return myDataSet;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps
thanks

Comment: This helps, I really appreciate it

Comment: With this i can only fire one time i.e here i can only get the textchanged event in itemcode while i also need it with other textbox and comboboxes in datagridview

Comment: Morning. I've updated my answer. The CellChangedEvent does fire for every column that you change. I've added  a switch statement to show how to handle the different columns changing based on the col index.

Answer (score 1):

If you use entity framework (since you do not specify much of your code) you can do it this way:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
          var query = from p in db.Items_
                    where p.itemCode== this.mydatagrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                    select p;
        this.mydatagrid.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (var items in query)
        {

            mydatagrid.Rows.Add(
                                         items.barcode.ToString(),
                                         items.itemName.ToString(),
                                         items.quantity.ToString(),
                                         items.rate.ToString()
                                         //etc
                );
        }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    }
```

PS: keep in mind that this example is vulnerable to sql injections.